# how to use if conditions for post request data in php

Tags: php

```
    <?php
    $answer1;
    $answer2;
    $answer4;
    $answer5;
    $answer6;
    $answer7;
    $answer8;
    $answer9;
    $answer10; 
    $_POST["counter"] === 0;


    if($answer1 == 'question-1-answers-a'
    $_POST["counter"]++;
    else{
        $_POST["counter"] == $_POST["counter"]
        }
```

The purpose of this segment of my code is to keep track the number of correct answers the user is getting on the quiz. The primary issue is that I keep getting an error saying unexpected $_POST["counter"] on this line:

```
$_POST["counter"]++;
```

And based on the research I have done, I doubt that the error is only in this line. So if anyone has any advice at all, please share.

Comment: There are a variety of errors in your code.  First, you never close the parentheses in your `if` condition (which is the error it's telling you about).  But beyond that, `$_POST["counter"]++;` doesn't really make sense.  And neither does that `else` block.  Or pretty much any of the lines before all of this.

Comment: @David The `$_POST["counter"] === 0;` does?

Comment: Look at your if-Clause, it's missing a ). Additionally it doesn't make sense to do something like `$_POST["counter"]++;`

Comment: @icecub: Honestly, none of it does.

Comment: Regarding the line you mention in the post, you need to look carefully at the structure of the `if` statement. You've not enclosed the test value in parenthesis, nor have you put the "true" clause in braces.

Comment: Once I added the parentheses, another error popped down below to the last line of this segment saying unexpected }.

Comment: $_POST["counter"]++;  What this is meant to do is to increment the counter by one when the correct answer is passed. So what would I have to change about it to make it make sense?

Comment: @MouradKhalil Use a regular variable. `$_POST` is a global used to retrieve user input. It makes no sense to use `$_POST` at all here. Just do `$counter = 0;` instead.

Comment: @jfadich I would, but I want to pass along the score from this quiz to another page

Comment: @MouradKhalil using the `$_POST` global won't help you achieve that though. `$_SESSION` would be a better option if both pages are on the same server. Otherwise you'll have to include the values in whatever call you make to that page. `$_POST` is for reading input, not passing input to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

The comments above are all valid. For an explicit answer to the question title, if conditions work as follows:

```
if ($case) {
  //do this
} else {
  //do this
}
```

When $case evaluates to some kind of true, then the first case happens. Otherwise the second will.
Note the use of braces.

The `=` operator is only for assigning variables. The `==` and `===` operators are only for comparing variables and will evaulate to either `true` or `false`. Your statement of `$_POST["counter"] === 0` is essentially the same as writing either `true` or `false`, depending on the contents of `$_POST["counter"]`.

A properly formatted version of your code is as follows:

```
<?php
    $answer1;
    $answer2;
    $answer4;
    $answer5;
    $answer6;
    $answer7;
    $answer8;
    $answer9;
    $answer10; 
    $_POST["counter"] = 0;


    if ($answer1 == 'question-1-answers-a') {
        $_POST['counter'] = $_POST['counter'] + 1 ;
    } else {
        $_POST['counter'] = $_POST['counter']
    }
?>
```

You also do not need to declare variables as you did with `$answerX`. Just delcare it on assignment.