# how to use if conditions for session request data in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $answer1 = 'question-1-answers-a';
    $answer2 = 'question-2-answers-a';
    $answer3 = 'question-3-answers-a';
    $answer4 = 'question-4-answers-a';
    $answer5 = 'question-5-answers-a';
    $answer6 = 'question-6-answers-d';
    $answer7 = 'question-7-answers-c';
    $answer8 = 'question-8-answers-c';
    $answer9 = 'question-9-answers-b';
    $answer10 = 'question-10-answers-b'; 
    $_SESSION["counter"] = 0;


    if ($answer1 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;



    if($answer2 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;


    if($answer3 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;

    if($answer4 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;

    if($answer5 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;

    if($answer6 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;

    if($answer7 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;

    if($answer8 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;

    if($answer9 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;

    if($answer10 == true)
    $_SESSION['counter']++;
?>
```

This part of my code is supposed to grade the quiz and pass on the users score to the next page. I found that it only passed along the number 0. This showed me that none of my if conditions are working as they should be. If anyone has any advice, please share.

```
 <p>
            1.What is President Donald Trump’s campaign tagline
        </p>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers-a" id="question-1-answers-a" value="a" />
            <label for="question-1-answers-a" class="fwrd LabelA">a-Let’s make America great again</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers-b" id="question-1-answers-b" value="b" />
            <label for="question-1-answers-b" class="fwrd LabelA">b-Yes we can</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers-c" id="question-1-answers-c" value="c" />
            <label for="question-1-answers-c" class="fwrd LabelA">c-Together we are stronger</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers-d" id="question-1-answers-d" value="d" />
            <label for="question-1-answers-d" class="fwrd LabelA">d-We can and we will</label>
        </div>
        <br/>
```

Comment: what the point of `$_SESSION["counter"] == $_SESSION["counter"]`

Comment: For that matter, what's the point of `$_SESSION["counter"] === 0;`?  Did you mean `$_SESSION["counter"] = 0;`?  And your `if` conditions will never be true because you're comparing values for variables that you have only declared but never set values to.  As for the question, why do you think your second condition is "not syntactically correct"?  What's the *actual error* you're seeing?

Comment: It was meant to mean the alternative to     $_SESSION['counter']++;
So it just means keep everything the same.

Comment: @MouradKhalil: You don't have to remind a value to stay the same.  It will stay the same until it's set to something else.  And `==` doesn't set values anyway, it *compares* them.

Comment: Already voted to close as unclear what you're asking, but just noticed that this is also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550126/how-to-use-if-conditions-for-post-request-data-in-php  Don't re-ask the same question.  You were already receiving help in your other question.  Improve that question.

Comment: @David  DO you think it would be better to declare answer1 for example as being equal to question-1-answer-1 and have the if condition be something like  if($answer1) == true)                   
                         {$_SESSION["counter"]++;                                                                                                   
                         }

Comment: @MouradKhalil: What would that accomplish?  *I think* it would be better to start with some introductory tutorials on PHP and to define one piece at a time whatever it is you're actually trying to do here.  This code is a mess of random typing that looks vaguely PHP-ish but doesn't actually make any sense.  Think smaller, what *specifically* is one thing you are trying to do in your code?

Comment: @David So should I just remove the else?

Comment: @David I am trying to create a counter for the correct answers.

Comment: @MouradKhalil: Sure, couldn't hurt since it doesn't do anything.  Of course, neither does the rest of the code in the question.  What you *shouldn't* do is keep randomly trying things like that and hoping for the best.  What you *should* do is start with some introductory tutorials on PHP and learn how it works.

Comment: @David I already did, but, as you can see, I am still struggling, so do you have any other advice?

Comment: @MouradKhalil: Scrap what you have and go find more tutorials and keep learning.  And, honestly, think *smaller* at first.  Just start with the absolute basics.  Setting a variable value and displaying on the page, changing its value and displaying it again, writing a basic `if` to check its value and display something conditionally, etc.  Honestly, I'm not trying to be mean here, but the code you have now *makes no sense* and *does nothing*.

Comment: @David: I have done my research, but I am still having trouble getting the if conditions to work properly.

Comment: Ok, look at your first variable, $answer1.  You set it to a string.  And then you check if it's "true".  It's *a string*, not *a boolean*.  What are you even trying to check in that if statement?  You set the variable to a specific string, so it now equals that specific string.  I can't stress enough how what you're doing makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: @David I've added another section of my code tha might help clarify what it is that I am trying to do. 'question-1-answers-a'; is meant to be the name of a multiple choice option.