# What is wrong with my quiz grading algorithm?

Tags: php

```
  <?php
    $answer1 = 'question-1-answers';
    $answer2 = 'question-2-answers';
    $answer3 = 'question-3-answers';
    $answer4 = 'question-4-answers';
    $answer5 = 'question-5-answers';
    $answer6 = 'question-6-answers';
    $answer7 = 'question-7-answers';
    $answer8 = 'question-8-answers';
    $answer9 = 'question-9-answers';
    $answer10 = 'question-10-answers';
    $_SESSION["counter"] = 0;


    if ($answer1 == "a")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }


    if ($answer2 == "a")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }


    if ($answer3 == "a")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }

    if ($answer4 == "a")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }

    if ($answer5 == "a")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }

    if ($answer6 == "d")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }

    if ($answer7 == "c")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }

    if ($answer8 == "c")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }

    if ($answer9 == "b")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }

    if ($answer10 == "b")
    {
        $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }
?>
```

So this piece of code is meant to grade my quiz and pass on the number of correct answers, initially 0, to the next page. The problem is that when I do run my code, the number of correct answers always turns out 0 no matter how many correct answers I get. Any advice?

```
 <p>
            5.What is the country with the highest Muslim population?
        </p>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-1-answers-a" value="a" />
            <label for="question-1-answers-a" class="fwrd LabelA">a-Indonseia</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-1-answers-b" value="b" />
            <label for="question-5-answers-b" class="fwrd LabelA">b-Pakistan</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-1-answers-c" value="c" />
            <label for="question-5-answers-c" class="fwrd LabelA">c-Saudi arabia</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-1-answers-d" value="d" />
            <label for="question-5-answers-d" class="fwrd LabelA">d-India</label>
        </div>
        <br/>
```

Comment: you posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/43557475/1415724 - had I known beforehand, I'd of closed it as an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Fred -ii:I did, but using a completely different approach. If you had bothered reading it, you would know.

Answer (score 1):

Following condition will never be true `if ($answer1 == "a")`, its equivalent to `"question-1-answers" == "a"`.

It should be something like `if($_REQUEST[$answer1] == 'a')`

Comment: Would I have to call any function to add the $_REQUEST?

Comment: @MouradKhalil No need. [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: if ($_REQUEST[$answer1] == "a")
        {
            $_SESSION["counter"]++;
        }                                                                                                                                 I tried this, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MouradKhalil How are you submitting the answers to backend (php)?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Are you using something like this ?`<form action="yourphpfile.php" method="post">`

Comment: Found a simple example online. Check this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-quiz-php) for guide.

Comment: I don't have one. So should the action refer to the file I am currently on or the file I am redirecting the information to?

Comment: The action should point to the php file where you are checking the answers

Comment: Yes the form should go around all your question & answers input field

Comment: It still doesn't work. Do you think that it would  be a good idea to post my whole code for you and others to see my code clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `session_start()` on top of everything